# base controller for setting language cookie for new users not excuted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, globalization

I using this code for globalization and set language cookie for new users and that is a base class `BaseController`. but it not executed at all. please help me.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

namespace App1.Models
{
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private const string LanguageCookieName = "cookie_lang";
    protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[LanguageCookieName];
        string lang;
        lang = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultCulture"] ?? "en-US";

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            lang = cookie.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            var httpCookie = new HttpCookie(LanguageCookieName, lang)
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
            };
            HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(httpCookie);
        }
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
        base.ExecuteCore();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good article for multi language. It seems to me very good .
http://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/

Comment: Nice one. Clear and simple article. Thank you

Comment: tnx @mohammad-aliyan